# text parsing hangs

Tags: wpf, while-loop

hi i have the following code:

```
        private void Textparsing()
        {               
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Masterbuildpropertiespath))                 
            {                    
                String line;
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                while ((line != null))
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("Exec_mail"))
                    {
                        ExecmailCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                }                 
            }
}
```

When i use this function, it seems that the application just hangs there without doing anything. Is this something wrong with the while loop here?

EDIT 1:

the code i am using now has the error: 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a definition for 'Readline' and no extension method 'Readline' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' could be found

code:

```
        private void Textparsing()
        {               
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Masterbuildpropertiespath))                 
            {                    
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        if (sr.Readline().StartsWith("Exec_mail"))
                        {
                            ExecmailCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
                        }
                    }              
            }               
}
```

error is found in this line:

```
if (sr.Readline().StartsWith("Exec_mail"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StreamReader.Peek()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx) to determine the end of file:

```
private void Textparsing()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Masterbuildpropertiespath))
    {
        while (sr.Peek()>=0)              
        {
            if (sr.ReadLine().StartsWith("Exec_mail"))
            {
                ExecmailCheckBox.IsChecked = true;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I ran the code with a sample text file located at D:\aa.txt with 4 lines of text in it as:
Exec_mail
abcd
Exec_mail
efgh
Exec_mail

using this code:

```
private void Textparsing()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\aa.txt")) 
    {
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        { 
            if (sr.ReadLine().StartsWith("Exec_mail")) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("yes");
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

And it showed yes three times.

Comment: hi in `if (sr.ReadLine().StartsWith("Exec_mail"))`, i get the error 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a definition for 'Readline' and no extension method 'Readline' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' could be found

Comment: can you edit your question and post the exact code you are using right now?

Comment: Is your Masterbuildpropertiespath variable is of type string representing the location of file you want to open? I have put some sample code in my answer, please see.

Comment: @akshay j the problem is..i can't compile it now to run the code

Comment: @akshay j yes. it is a variable string type

Comment: The error says that System.IO.StreamReader class does not contain a method named ReadLine but it DOES contain that method. Can you run my sample code along with the text file and see if it works?

Comment: ok the problem lies here: should have been `ReadLine` instead of `Readline`